# Proposal to separate tag wiki from tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think it would be better reading experience if tag synonyms are moved to a separated page from tag wiki, or at least have some clear separation.

For example take a look at [jquery tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info). There are 3 lines of useful info and then half a page explaining what tag synonyms are without clear separation from a wiki article (line is not enough imo).

Comment: So, maybe just a bigger space? Seperating the pages will just create tiny pages

Comment: Jeff wanted me to do this, I'm a bit concerned about tiny pages

Comment: @waffles: Small pages are better than cluttered pages, IMO.